# Redirect 301 htacces with question mark 404 file not found

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I want to redirect

/fr/verhuur_details.asp?nav=3&id=106
TO
/fr/location/knikarm

Im using this rule in my .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301    /fr/verhuur_details.asp?nav=3&id=106    /fr/location/knikarm
```

But i always receive 404 not found

But code below works perfect

```
Redirect 301    /fr/verhuur_details.asp    /fr/location/knikarm
```

everything is working fine. So my guess is that the ? is causing this problem. Any kind of help will be well appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not so much used to `Redirect`, but with `RewriteRule`, you could go like this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^nav=3&id=106$
RewriteRule ^fr/verhuur_details.asp$ /fr/location/knikarm? [R=301,L]
```

This should work.

Note : if you want keep query string after redirect, you'll need to delete `?` at the end :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^nav=3&id=106$
RewriteRule ^fr/verhuur_details.asp$ /fr/location/knikarm [R=301,L]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hellow, thanks for answering, problem is i have a list of 200 redirects :(